# Codeigniter this->db->query unidentified index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to execute the following query using CodeIgniter, but I am getting

> Unidentified index for ->row['code'];

```
public function getSExtension($id) {
  $temp = array();
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT extension_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zipcode_shipping WHERE `zip_code` = '" . $id . "'");
  if($query->num_rows) {
    foreach ($query->rows as $key => $value) {
      $code = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "extension WHERE `extension_id` = '" . $value['extension_id'] . "'")->row['code'];
      $this->language->load("shipping/".$code);
      $temp[] = $this->language->get('text_title');
    }
  }
  return $temp;
}
```

Comment: you are chaining the $row->['code'] with the query.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please edit your code to include all your code in the code block. This will help other users see your code better. You can include it by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: hey there. ever heard of sql injection? your code is wide open to it. you should definitely read about prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks everyone for response, I am new to this. before posting this query went through many links to get it clear but did not get anything which resolve my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not correctly retrieved a result set which requires a method call. As you have it you are trying to use db properties that don't exist i.e. `$query->rows` should probably be `$query->row_array()`.

[Documentation Here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

In the example below I use `result()` and `row()` instead of any "array" methods.

Try this.

```
$temp = array();
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT extension_id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."zipcode_shipping WHERE `zip_code` = '".$id."'");

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($query->result() as $value)
    {
        $code = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM ".DB_PREFIX."extension WHERE `extension_id` = '".$value->extension_id."'")->row()->code;
        $this->language->load("shipping/".$code);
        $temp[] = $this->language->get('text_title');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: I tried with the code but getting fatal error undefined stdClass Result()

Comment: I had a problem much like yours - I called a property instead of a method with `if($query->num_rows > 0)` It should be `if($query->num_rows() > 0)`. I edited the answer to be correct. Make the fix in your code and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, after making changes same problem occurring with num_rows(). I think i am missing something.

Comment: What is the exact error with `num_rows()`? My best guess is that `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT...);` is not working. Which would mean that `$query` is a `boolean` and not an `object`. Check to see if `$query === FALSE`.